# Why can't I cast back to a specific interface that was received through a gRPC call?

Tags: go, grpc

**The What**

I want to return through a gRPC call a struct which implements two interfaces `error` and my custom interface `Hater`.

The return struct will be returned as an error.

```
func (s ErrorTestServer) ErrorTest(ctx context.Context, _ *pb.EmptyMsg) (*pb.StatusMsg, error) {
    return &pb.StatusMsg{}, NewCustomError() // NewCustomError implements error and Hater
}
```

On a client side I want to cast received `err` which is `error` interface to `Hater` interface.

```
_, err = client.ErrorTest(context.Background(), &pb.EmptyMsg{})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(&err).Elem())

        if h, ok := err.(hater.Hater); ok { //Can't cast to hater.Hater interface
            h.Show()
        }
    }
```

**The Problem**

Client side returned error can not be casted to `Hater` interface.

```
if h, ok := err.(hater.Hater); ok { //Can't cast to hater.Hater interface
    h.Show()
}
```

**The How**

How to cast client side returned error to a `Hater` interface?

==================================

**client.go**

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    pb "main/errortest"
    "main/hater"
    "reflect"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/insecure"
)

func main() {
    conn, err := grpc.Dial("localhost:9090", grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()))
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    client := pb.NewErrorTestClient(conn)

    _, err = client.ErrorTest(context.Background(), &pb.EmptyMsg{})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(&err).Elem())

        if h, ok := err.(hater.Hater); ok { //Can't cast to hater.Hater interface
            h.Show()
        }
    }
}
```

**server.go**

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"

    pb "main/errortest"
    "main/hater"
)

type ErrorTestServer struct {
    pb.UnimplementedErrorTestServer
}

func (s ErrorTestServer) ErrorTest(ctx context.Context, _ *pb.EmptyMsg) (*pb.StatusMsg, error) {
    return &pb.StatusMsg{}, NewCustomError()
}

func NewCustomError() hater.CustomError {
    return hater.CustomError{
        Message: "Greetings from Bali!",
    }
}

func main() {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("localhost:%d", 9090))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }
    var opts []grpc.ServerOption

    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer(opts...)
    pb.RegisterErrorTestServer(grpcServer, ErrorTestServer{})

    if err := grpcServer.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        fmt.Print("failed to start server")
    }
}
```

**custom error which implements error and hater.go interfaces**

```
package hater

import "fmt"

type Hater interface {
    Show()
    error
}

type CustomError struct {
    Message string
}

func (e CustomError) Show() {
    fmt.Println(e.Message)
}

func (e CustomError) Error() string {
    return e.Message
}
```

Comment: gRPC does not transport go error objects. It transports a gRPC status which can contain a gRPC status code + error message. On the client you get a gRPC status error, not the custom error you sent. Best use https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/status errors (or implement the interface) to respond on server side, so there actually is a non-OK gRPC status if an error occurred. Otherwise the gRPC status will always be `0-OK`.

Comment: If you want to have the custom errors on client side again, you need to find a way to detect them from the information that is transported. e.g. by error message. Then re-create them on client side, best in a central location applied to all gRPC calls.

Comment: @TehSphinX yes I'm familiar with `gRPC.status`. I wanted to ask how can I achieve the desired behaviour in the topic.

Comment: @TehSphinX ah.. `On the client you get a gRPC status error, not the custom error ` - understand now

Comment: If you want to transport custom errors, you'd have to do that inside the response. Would be an option to additionally return the error in the response and define a proto message for it. That way you have the gRPC status error (to report the correct gRPC status code) AND the custom error from the response. Not sure however if the response is still returned on error or if it is nil.

Comment: @TehSphinX if you want to I can accept your answer

Comment: thx added as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gRPC` does not transport go error objects. It transports a gRPC status which can contain a gRPC status code + error message. On the client you get a gRPC status error, not the custom error you sent.

Best use [grpc status errors](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/status) (or implement the interface) to respond on server side, so there actually is a non-OK gRPC status if an error occurred. Otherwise the gRPC status will always be `0-OK`.

If you want to have the custom errors on client side again, you need to find a way to detect them from the information that is transported. e.g. by error message. Then re-create them on client side, best in a central location applied to all gRPC calls.

Another option if you want to transport custom errors, you'd have to do that inside the response. Additionally return the the custom error in the response and define a `proto` message for it. That way you have the gRPC status error (to report the correct gRPC status code) AND the custom error from the response.